# Dependent <material-dropdown-select>

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I want to link multiple `<material-dropdown-select>`, using `[(ngModel)]` + `(ngModelChange)`, making them dependent. (So not by using `*ngFor` + `<material-select-item>`.)

But I do not find how to make these `<material-dropdown-select>` dependent, such that when the "parent" is updated, the "first child" is updated/reset, and then when the first child is selected, the second is reset/updated, and so on.

I tried with `querySelector()` but obviously, this is not the good way.

Maybe with `ViewChild`/`ViewChildren` but the options list is not updated???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally get what I needed.

I used `@ViewChild` to target the element in the page.

But changing the options "was tricky", as I had to first :

- `MaterialDropdownSelectComponent.options.dispose();`

then

- add the new list…

without the first step, the `SelectionOptions<dynamic>` is not updated…