# Manually insert Material Component inside Html Element

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

How to add inside a `DivElement` a list of Material Component, say `MaterialCheckboxComponent`?

`DivElement.children` is a `List<Element>`, and I cannot see how to cast `List<MaterialCheckboxComponent>` to `List<Element>`.

How can I achieve what is done with `MaterialCheckboxComponent` manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/note/faq/component-loading is a section about dynamically adding components

> ```
> @Component(
>   selector: 'ad-view',
>   template: r'''
>     This component is sponsored by:
>     <template #currentAd></template>
>   ''',
> )
> class AdViewComponent {
>   final ComponentLoader _loader;
>
>   AdViewComponent(this._loader);
>
>   @ViewChild('currentAd', read: ViewContainerRef)
>   ViewContainerRef currentAd;
>
>   @Input()
>   set component(ComponentFactory component) {
>     _loader.loadNextToLocation(component, currentAd);
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: No, you can ohly imoeratively remove imperatively added components.

Comment: _I rewrite my previous comment (there were a mistake, here in bold):_ So it is not possible to update, from one component, a tag related to the template's Component? For example something like (which does not work): var target = querySelector('#target'); target.children.clear(); var listCheckBox = List<MaterialCheckboxComponent> (); **target**.children.add(listCheckBox);

Comment: Same answer as before.

Comment: I am not sure of what you mean by _you can only imperatively remove imperatively added components._. What is meant here by "_remove_"? Because I can update [`StringSelectionOptions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592943/dependent-material-dropdown-select), by swapping the content, not using `Imperative Component Loading` per se.

Comment: If you add a component using the code in my answer (imperatively), then you can also remove it imperatively, otherwise you can use declarative approaches like `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`.

Comment: So Material Component are `Imperative Component`. Makes sense.
As for the 'declarative approaches', it will not work, as the content is loaded from the server, according to user choices. So I guess that with `Imperative Component`, I should be able to pass variables to built the Component accordingly to the retrieved data.

Comment: No, components added using `_loader.loadNextToLocation(component, currentAd);
  }` are imperatively added components. Components added using markup `<my-component></my-component>` are declaratively added components.

Comment: Ok, but, now remains one question. After checking the doc, `Imperative Component` _**could be a good solution**_, but I cannot see how to pass data, from a `Component` to an `Imperative Component`. I will need to update the `Imperative Component` according to the user input. In one question: **How to update the `Imperative Component` either by using - one of its setter, - or by destroying one instance and passing in the constructor of new instance some values.**

Comment: You can't use data-binding. ` _loader.loadXxx(...)` returns a https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular/angular/ComponentRef-class and the https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular/angular/ComponentRef/instance getter returns the components class instance where you can access getters/setters/fields and call methods or register event listeners to streams.

Comment: So this is not an option. I must update the content…

Comment: I don't understand you comment. Just pass the content to the declarative component that imperatively adds other components and pass the content along to the imperatively created component as explained in my previous comment.

Comment: **_Maybe I am wrong_**, but I see **no way to update from the  `Component` the `Imperative Component`**. Sure, I can access to these getters, and so, from the `Imperative Component` with the `_loader`, but not from the `Component`. So it is useless.

Comment: I don't understand. You can pass from the component that calls `_loader` to the added component. This imperatively added component can use data-binding in its template to render the content.

Comment: **If I follow** the [the doc](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/note/faq/component-loading#load-next-to-a-location), I cannot access, with `ComponentFactory`, the `_loader` properties, from outside the `Imperative Component`.
But, thinking about it, I should be able to access it (`_loader`), 1) **if I do not use `ComponentFactory`**, 2) and add a getter inside the `Imperative Component`, 3) finally create an instance of this `Imperative Component` in a `Component`. But, sorry, I still do not understand how you can do otherwise. Can you show me?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with the loader. You get a `ComponentRef` back when you create a component and with this `ComponentRef` you can update its properties.

Comment: '_loader_' is from the doc, you get a `final ComponentLoader _loader;`. But I [zapped the **Migration part**](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/note/faq/component-loading#migration), as I think I was not concerned… But I will take a look at this.

Comment: Ok, I get it right. **Thanks for your patience.** You lead me to the right way, but **I have been trapped by this poorly written documentation**…

Comment: Please create issues in github.com/dart-lang/angular if you have suggestions where the docs could be improved.